# Avoid to overwrite values inside ObservableCollection (C#, WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, observable, observablecollection

I have list of working days

[image]

bind to `DataGrid`:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyConceptItems}"
```

Then I'm getting from json other list and try to match using date:

```
public ObservableCollection<MyDataConcept> MyConceptItems { get; set; }

public void GetSheet(string fd, string ld){
 string period = "\"" + fd + "\",\"" + ld + "\"";
 string result = Task.Run(() => MyMethodAsync("getsheet", GetApiKeyAsync(), "," + period)).
                                GetAwaiter().GetResult();
 MyObject resultparsed = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<MyObject>(result);

  foreach (var item in resultparsed.result.items) {                
   foreach (var existingItem in MyConceptItems) {
    if (existingItem.DateColumn == item.entryDate) {
                    existingItem.PColumn = item.pName;
                    existingItem.TColumn = item.aName;
                    existingItem.HSpend = item.formattedDuration;
 }}}};
```

My problem is: when I'm geting from json **two result with the same date**  then into MyConceptItems is displayed only the one(last) item, probably is overwritten.

**Example**:

`MyConecptItems`:

```
  Date     | PColumn
2018-09-03 |  A2
2018-09-04 |  B
2018-09-05 |  C2
```

From `Json`:

```
   Date     | PName
2018-09-03  |  A
2018-09-03  |  A2
2018-09-04  |  B
2018-09-05  |  C
2018-09-05  |  C2
```

**UPDATE:**

Im trying to do like below:

```
foreach (var item in resultparsed.result.items) {                
   foreach (var existingItem in MyConceptItems) {
    if (existingItem.DateColumn == item.entryDate) 
     if (existingItem.IsExist == false){
                            existingItem.IsExist = true;
                            existingItem.ProjectColumn = item.projectName;
                            existingItem.TaskColumn = item.activityName;
                            existingItem.HoursSpend = item.formattedDuration;
      }
      else
      {
      MyConceptItems.Add(new MyDataConcept(item.entryDate, item.entryDayName, 
                         item.projectName, item.activityName, item.formattedDuration); 
      } 
 }}
```

but then have this message:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 
'Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.'
```

Comment: This is because you overwrite those values in your loop: `existingItem.PColumn = item.pName;`.

Comment: so what can I do with this? create MyConceptItems?

Comment: So you want to display several items with the same date? Or what is your issue? How do you know when to update an existing item or add a new one?

Comment: If I have under one date, couple of items, I want to display all of them, date will be the same but other column are diffrent (PName, TColumn, etc...)

Comment: just update my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't modify a collection while enumerating it using a `foreach` loop. Try something like this:

```
foreach (var item in resultparsed.result.items)
{
    var existingItem = MyConceptItems.FirstOrDefault(x => x.DateColumn == item.entryDate);
    if(existingItem != null)
    {
        //update properties...
    }
    else
    {
        //add new item
        MyConceptItems.Add(new MyDataConcept(item.entryDate, item.entryDayName,
            item.projectName, item.activityName, item.formattedDuration);
    }
}
```

Comment: I change the if to => existingItem.IsExist == false, and now it's ok....I just need to sort it

Comment: You mean that you want to sort MyConceptItems?

Comment: yes, because new Item is added on the end, and I need to sort by entryDayName

Comment: That's another issue. Please ask a new question if you have another issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over the ObservableCollection with the line

```
foreach (var existingItem in MyConceptItems) {
```

Looping in this fashion uses the collection's iterator. You are then adding an item inside that loop:

```
MyConceptItems.Add(new MyDataConcept(...
```

You cannot use a collection enumerator while you are modifying the collection itself (modifying the properties of an item in the collection is fine).

Consider changing your code to use one of these handy [IList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) extension methods which allow you to specify a predicate (a condition to select a specific object): [Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.collection-1.system-collections-ilist-contains?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_ObjectModel_Collection_1_System_Collections_IList_Contains_System_Object_), [Any](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_Any__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__), [Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_Select__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__) or [SingleOrDefault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_SingleOrDefault__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__). If these methods do not return the item you expect then you can add a new item to the collection.